# SQLite - does it lock the table, the database or the buffer?

Tags: sqlite, concurrency

I'm new at SQLite (currently learning with sqlite3) and  one point was not clear for me: how does the access concurrency works on sqlite. When the lock occurs, does it lock the table, the database or the buffer?

I've read about it in this page: https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html , but english is not my mother tongue, so I got a little bit confused.

Comment: It locks the database file.